# Give a title to each sql query output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a sql script which is nothing but a combination of multiple "Select" queries like:

```
Select * from ABC
Select * from CD
Select * from EN
```

Now when I execute it, I use to get output like

```
<output 1>
<output 2>
<output 3>
```

Requirement: I need some title to be displayed for each of the output.

To be more clear,I want output like:

```
Heading for Output of SQL query 1  
 output 1  
Heading for Output of SQL query 2  
output 2  
Heading for Output of SQL query 3  
output 3
```

Database is SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: so you just need one field of same type from the 3 tables ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please, specify, which database do you use?

Comment: Try one of my solutions. In your case 1st or 3rd will do.

Comment: Thanks ,it worked with single quotes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There're a lot of ways for achieving this. What exactly do you need this for?

**1.**

```
SELECT 'ABC' As title
Select * from ABC

SELECT 'CD' As title
Select * from CD

SELECT 'ABC' As title
Select * from EN
```

**2.**

```
Select 'ABC' As title, * from ABC
Select 'CD' As title, * from CD
Select 'EN' As title, * from EN
```

**3.**

Works for **SQL Server**. Not sure about other db's

```
PRINT 'ABC'
Select * from ABC

PRINT 'CD'
Select * from CD

PRINT 'ABC'
Select * from EN
```

Comment: On SQL Server 2008:Option 3rd worked with PRINT 'ABC' ,not with PRINT "ABC".Thanks

Comment: You're right. Updated answer. Please, accept the answer if it's right.

Comment: You can use PRINT "ABC" if you use SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF before the PRINT statement